# DrawerLayout: How to make this Custom Layout in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a drawer in which I want to achieve layout posted in the below screenshot.

`AllTasks, Today, Complete and Incomplete` with `numbers` are fixed. The user cannot add these. Already added by me. `CreateList and Settings` as well.

`MyList` which is added by the user and he can add more like Food, Sports, Reading etc.

`Divider` as well, maybe after 1 row or 3 rows to show as groups.

Should I use `ListView`?. Any suggestion, please.

[image: https://us.v-cdn.net/5019960/uploads/editor/ed/wtgcly2nls78.jpg]

[image: https://us.v-cdn.net/5019960/uploads/editor/2t/0g4rbo6rufsm.png]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of methods to do that the first one using ListView like that:

```
drawer: new Drawer(
      child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
            accountName: const Text('Test Widget'),
            accountEmail: const Text('test.widget@example.com'),
            margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
            onDetailsPressed: () {},
          ),
          new Expanded(
            child: new ListView(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
              children: <Widget>[
                new Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: _drawerContents.map((String id) {
                    return new ListTile(
                      leading: new CircleAvatar(child: new Text(id)),
                      title: new Text('Drawer item $id'),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                ),
                // The drawer's "details" view.
                new Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new ListTile(
                      leading: const Icon(Icons.add),
                      title: const Text('Add account'),
                    ),
                    new ListTile(
                      leading: const Icon(Icons.settings),
                      title: const Text('Manage accounts'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
```

But it is efficient only with a limited number of list item because all the item of that ListView are rendered at once.

The other way to do that is using a ListView.builder like that:

```
drawer: new Drawer(
      child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
            accountName: const Text('Test Test'),
            accountEmail: const Text('test@example.com'),
            margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
            onDetailsPressed: () {},
          ),
          new Expanded(
            child: new ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                  new EntryItem(data[index]),
              itemCount: data.length,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

In that way your list elements will be rendered one by one during scrolling. You should create one model for both your hardcoded elements and your variable elements and then create a different ListTile (in the example EntryItem).

Let me know if you need more details.

PS. EntryItem example below:

```
class EntryItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const EntryItem(this.entry);

  final Entry entry;

  Widget _buildTiles(Entry root) {
      if(root.counter != null) {
          return new ListTile(
              leading: Icon(root.icon),
              title: Text(root.title),
              trailing: new Text(root.counter)
          );
      } else {
        return new ListTile(
              leading: Icon(root.icon),
              title: Text(root.title),
          );
      }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildTiles(entry);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. Let me test that and I get back to you.

Comment: what will be the EntryItem(data[index]). Can you post sample code please.

Comment: I added an EntryItem example in the answer.

Comment: i am sorry to ask again. Can you paste Entry class structure with dummy data to fill as an example. I will accept the answer. Thanks for the help.